# Python Chatterbot "Errno 22"

Tags: python, python-2.7, chatterbot

I'm trying to train a chatbot, and most of the data is in text files.

I pull:

```
Matt said you have a "shit load" of dining dollars. I have almost none so if you're willing to sell, I'm willing to buy.
```

from the text file, but when the chatterbot corpus tries to train the bot, it reads the above as:

```
'Matt said you have a "shit load" of dining dollars\\ I have almost none so if you\'re willing to sell, I\'m willing to buy\\\n'
```

How can I fix this?

This is my code:

```
def train_from_text():
    #chatbot.set_trainer(ListTrainer)
    directory = basedir + "Text Trainers"
    files = find_files_in_directory(directory)
    for file in files:
        conversation = []
        file_name = directory+"/"+file
        with open(file_name, 'r') as to_read:
            for line in to_read:
                conversation.append(line)
        chatbot.train(conversation)
```

Please excuse the swearing, its the data I was given.

**Edit:** Full error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/Jason Chatterbot/Jason Chat.py", line 102, in <module>
control()
  File "E:/Jason Chatterbot/Jason Chat.py", line 96, in control
train_from_text()
  File "E:/Jason Chatterbot/Jason Chat.py", line 58, in train_from_text
chatbot.train(conversation)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\chatterbot\trainers.py", line 119, in train
corpora = self.corpus.load_corpus(corpus_path)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\chatterbot_corpus\corpus.py", line 98, in load_corpus
corpus_data = self.read_corpus(file_path)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\chatterbot_corpus\corpus.py", line 63, in read_corpus
with io.open(file_name, encoding='utf-8') as data_file:
IOError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'Matt said you have a "shit load" of dining dollars\\ I have almost none so if you\'re willing to sell, I\'m willing to buy\\\r\n'
```

Comment: do you want to get rid of all the `/`?

Answer (score 0):

Without looking at a larger subset of the data, seems like it's replacing single quotes (') with escaped single quotes (\'), actual newline characters, with escaped newlines (\n) and periods with double backslashes (\)

A simple string replace might fix it for you, depending on how bad the data is getting munged. Try changing

```
conversation.append(line)
```

to

```
conversation.append(line.replace("\\'","'").replace('\\\\','.').replace("\\n","\n"))
```

We're basically trying to reverse those substitutions that are being made automatically.

Comment: I still get the same error (pasted above, too long for comments)

Comment: Ok, it seems like somehow that string is being read from the file and somewhere in your program it is actually trying to open that string as a file. Invalid argument on io.open. I would add a print statement before you open the file and after you open the file displaying what "file_name" is, because it seems to be related to that

Comment: That's where I got "'Matt said you have a "shit load" of dining dollars\\ I have almost none so if you\'re willing to sell, I\'m willing to buy\\\n'" from. I've added print statements everywhere and it seems to be an error arising from the chatterbot library listtrainer function itself, but I can't figure out where exactly it arises from. Trying your fix at each step doesn't solve the problem either, I still get that lovely error

Comment: Yeah, if it's an error with the library, that's a more involved issue. My final suggestion would be that it might be related to the double quotes in the string. Perhaps try removing the double quotes from the string and see if you're getting the same error. If that changes things, we have a path forward from there.

Comment: They updated the library so this method doesn't work anymore. Thanks for your time :D